# Set the right two characters (if there are any) to capitals?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Below is my data:

```
Data Here 94/452O
Data more 94/4522i
Data bla 94/111
Data bla 94/459es
Data bla 94/444
```

`items` is automatically generated by some previous code but it could come out like:
`items = ["Data Here 94/452O", "Data more 94/4522i", "Data bla 94/111", "Data bla 94/459es", "Data bla 94/444"]`

Now currently I'm appending the following:

`"\n".join(items).replace("4ke", "9")` with a few other .replaces however I want it to replace/change the characters on the end of the numbers with a capital letter instead of lowercase...

Output:

```
Data Here 94/452O
Data more 94/4522I
Data bla 94/111
Data bla 94/459ES
Data bla 94/444
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
items = ["Data Here 94/452O", "Data more 94/4522i", "Data bla 94/111", "Data bla 94/459es", "Data bla 94/444"]

items = [item[:-2] + item[-2:].upper() for item in items]

print items
```

**Output**

```
['Data Here 94/452O', 'Data more 94/4522I', 'Data bla 94/111', 'Data bla 94/459ES', 'Data bla 94/444']
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> items = ["Data Here 94/452O", "Data more 94/4522i", "Data bla 94/111", "Data bla 94/459es", "Data bla 94/444"]
>>> for item in items:
...     print re.sub(r'([a-z]+)$', lambda m:m.group(1).upper(), item)
...     
Data Here 94/452O
Data more 94/4522I
Data bla 94/111
Data bla 94/459ES
Data bla 94/444
```

Answer (score 2):

Use slice notation with [`str.upper`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.upper):

```
>>> item = "Data bla 94/459es"
>>> item[:-2]
'Data bla 94/459'
>>> item[-2:]
'es'
>>> item[-2:].upper()
'ES'
>>> item[:-2] + item[-2:].upper()
'Data bla 94/459ES'
```

---

```
>>> items = ["Data Here 94/452O", "Data more 94/4522i", "Data bla 94/111", "Data bla 94/459es", "Data bla 94/444"]
>>> [item[:-2] + item[-2:].upper() for item in items]
['Data Here 94/452O', 'Data more 94/4522I', 'Data bla 94/111', 'Data bla 94/459ES', 'Data bla 94/444']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, on each line. It's the simplest answer, using slices:

```
line = line[:-2] + line[-2:].upper()
```

The above assumes that up to two letters appear at the end; notice that `upper()` won't have any effect on numbers, so it's perfectly safe to use it. For example:

```
line = 'Data bla 94/111'
line[:-2] + line[-2:].upper()
=> 'Data bla 94/111'

line = 'Data bla 94/459es'
line[:-2] + line[-2:].upper()
=> 'Data bla 94/459ES'
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution without regexp:

```
print "\n".join(["%s %s" % (" ".join(x.split()[0:-1]), x.split()[-1].upper()) for x in items])
```

Output:

```
Data Here 94/452O
Data more 94/4522I
Data bla 94/111
Data bla 94/459ES
Data bla 94/444
```